# React native audio record recordings do not play in web or in android

Tags: react-native

When I convert recordings from İOS and Android to MP4, they cannot be played in web and IOS. React native expo AV library I use.

I am wondering I am doing wrong. Is there a format I can convert all to MP4 so it can be played acorss all devices.

I try to convert them to MP4. but it cannot be played.